# How to get photo and contact information of user on pardot email template?

Tags: pardot

I am designing an email template in pardot. for displaying salesforce data i am using prospect fields. for simple fields like name and phone number i am using variables like %%firstname%% and %%phone%%. Contact has lookup relationship with User. i want to display user's photo and contact information on email template with dynamic variables. Can any one please help me to display salesforce images on pardot email template from a specified contact record. any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Balayesu

Answer (score 0):

You may use Attachment Object in Pardot.Pardot will sync attachment from salesforce.You can't create attachment in pardot.Use attachment here in pardot email template.
There may be on more way.If you put images in documents(sales force) make it public ,so that it is externally accessible.And put its url in contacts url type field.Now you can get the image like in Pardot.

Comment: I have used %%user_html_signature%%